# Create an Automation that imports data to a Data Extension depending on the file name on a sftp

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automation

I am trying to upload data into a Data Extension by uploading a CSV file to the sftp. An Automation should then compare the csv name with the Data Extension name and then upload it into that Data Extension

Example: I am uploading the file test_123.csv to the sftp. Then I want the data extension "test_123" to be filled with the CSV content.

The problem is that I have to pre select a Data Extension in all activities. I am not able to upload content dynamically to a data extension by name that way. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. SFMC does not allow users access to this SFTP file data publicly.

I have been told that there is a security risk if they were to open up where this info is stored and processed to the public, so it is not a viable option. You could talk to your SF Rep and see if they can build a custom solution for you via SF Services, but other than that, I do not see this as something possible internal to SFMC.

A workaround people do is push all the data into a single staging table and then have a 'flag' column inside the DE to show where that data should be moved to.

Otherwise you could create a subdirectory in your FTP and have a bunch of file drop automations targeting it with entry requirements like 'contains test123' or 'begins with myde_1' etc. and then build an import activity to push to the correct DE for each of these. You can utilize the `%%BASEFILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%` to ensure it grabs the correct file.  It is a LOT more setup work, but it can achieve very similar results to your original request.